# Usage of context in gcloud go sdk for cloudresourcemanager

Tags: go, sdk, gcloud

I am following the official `go` [documentation](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/cloudresourcemanager/v1) for gcloud sdk.

As an initial step, I am trying to instantiate a `cloudresourcemanager` service.

What I cannot seem to understand (perhaps its my poor background on `go` contexts) is why a `context` is needed to instantiate such a service as indicated in the official usage example:

```
import "google.golang.org/api/cloudresourcemanager/v1"
...
ctx := context.Background()
cloudresourcemanagerService, err := cloudresourcemanager.NewService(ctx)
```

Unless I am missing sth, the docs do not go into details about this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the **Go** [**documentation**](https://blog.golang.org/context):

> In Go servers, each incoming request is handled in its own
>   **goroutine**. Request handlers often start additional goroutines to access backends such as databases and RPC services.
>
> The set of goroutines working on a request typically needs access to
>   **request-specific values** such as the identity of the end user, authorization tokens, and the request's deadline. When a request is
>   canceled or times out, all the goroutines working on that request
>   should exit quickly so the system can reclaim any resources they are
>   using.
>
> The **context** package makes it easy to pass request-scoped values,
>   cancelation signals, and deadlines across API boundaries to all the
>   goroutines involved in handling a request.

---

The **context.Background()** is the root of any Context tree:

> Background returns a non-nil empty context. It is never canceled, has
>   no deadline, and has no values. Background is typically used in main,
>   init, and tests, and as the top-level Context for incoming requests.